# Unable to insert data to sqlserver using webservices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am working on asp.net with web services, I need to insert data to sql server using web services.I am getting some and I have given below my code.

This is web service code

```
[WebMethod]
public void db_insert(string username, string address, string city, string state, string country)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Test_Emp values(@username,@address,@city,@state,@country)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state",state);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is website code

```
protected void btn_submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Service myform = new Service();
    myform.db_insert((txt_name).ToString(), (txt_address).ToString, (txt_address).ToString(), (txt_city).ToString(),(txt_state).ToString,(txt_country).ToString);
}
```

when i execute the program am getting error like

> 'Employeedetails.Service' does not contain a definition for
>   'db_insert' and no extension method 'db_insert' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Employeedetails.Service' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please, add the error.

Comment: 'Employeedetails.Service' does not contain a definition for 'db_insert' and no extension method 'db_insert' accepting a first argument of type 'Employeedetails.Service' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: Well....do you have a reference to that namespace or assembly?

Comment: Your insert statement is problematic because you didn't specify the columns. If your table definition changes your code is broken. Also, since you are not using stored procedures you might take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: This error has nothing to do with SQL, you have to refresh your web service reference inside visual studio.

Comment: still am getting same error

Comment: Your webcode looks a little suspicious to me. What is (txt_name).ToString()??? If you want the value from a textbox you get the Text property, not the string of the object.

Comment: Your application might have same class name with WebService name as "Service". So your service class doesn't have a method. Please check it first and refresh your webservice reference.